# Column comparison error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I am writing a macro that compares two columns on different sheets in excel.
The macro is as follows:

```
Sub Main()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim stNow As Date
    stNow = Now

    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("W3:W" & Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

    Dim varr As Variant
    varr = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("P3:P" & Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

    Dim x, y, match As Boolean
    For Each x In arr
        match = False
        For Each y In varr
            If x = y Then match = True
        Next y
        If Not match Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L" & Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = x
        End If
    Next

    Debug.Print DateDiff("s", stNow, Now)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If the colums are on the same sheets and there are no sheet references in the code, it works perfectly. But now it only copies the first cell from Sheet3 column W, altough this value already exists in the column in P on Sheet3.

Comment: You need to exit the innner loop when a match is found.  So change your if to: `If x = y Then : match = True : Exit For : End If` where the `:` are new lines.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I think your comment should be "You should exit ...", rather than "You need to exit ...".  Without the `Exit For` the code will still work, just not as efficiently.

Comment: No, without the exit match will always return the comparison of x to the last y in the array to the if statement. @YowE3K

Comment: @ScottCraner - No, the `If` statement is only setting `match` to `True`.  So, once set to `True` it stays `True` until you start looking at the next value of `x`.  (If the statement was `match = x = y`, then that would cause problems, but not written as `If x = y Then match = True`.)

Comment: @YowE3K you are correct.  Did not think that all the way through.  But I would prefer your MATCH version anyways as it will be faster than iterating at all.

Comment: @ScottCraner - That's not my `Match` version - that's Shai's

Comment: @YowE3K whatever, :) I'm sick and that's the excuse I am going with.

Comment: @ScottCraner - You're sick - Shai's tired - and I'm sick and tired of going to work.

Comment: I *highly* suggest taking a look at @ShaiRado's answer. It's a great answer, and can help you learn quite a lot in such a short macro.  The use of `Match()` is a great boon to the code's size and speed.  Perhaps even mark as the Answer, if you wish.  As for everyone else, go to work and get some sleep! Yeesh!

Comment: @BruceWayne  is that a yes? Or yesh? Also tired ? ;)

Comment: @ShaiRado yes and yeeeesh! It's been a long day here at Wayne Industries, and the night isn't looking any less busy ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you notice, when there are no sheet references, it works fine.

You need to always qualify `Range()`, `Rows.` and `Columns.`, otherwise it'll use whatever the `ActiveSheet` is.

The following should work for you.

```
Sub Main()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim stNow   As Date
stNow = Now

Dim arr     As Variant
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    arr = .Range("W3:W" & .Range("W" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With

Dim varr    As Variant
With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    varr = .Range("P3:P" & .Range("P" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With

Dim x, y, match As Boolean
For Each x In arr
    match = False
    For Each y In varr
        If x = y Then
            match = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next y
    If Not match Then
        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .Range("L" & .Range("L" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = x
        End With
    End If
Next

Debug.Print DateDiff("s", stNow, Now)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note: I added `With` statements to cut down on the repetitiveness of using `Worksheets("Sheetx").`  Also, updated the `If x = y` statement, per @ScottCraner's comment.

Also I see that you have a few undeclared variables.  I recommend adding `Option Explicit` to the very start (before `Sub Main()`) and declare all variables.

Comment: why not use `Application.Match` to cut the 2nd `For` loop searching through all the elements in the second array, it will save a lot of code run-time

Comment: @ShaiRado - Good point. I just fixed up the code as OP had it, but I recommend they look in to that.  Also, personally, I'd shy away from using `match` as a variable name, and perhaps use `isMatch` or something.

Answer (score 5):

Following @BruceWayne answer, you can replace the middle section of your code, and instead of using **2 x** `For` loops scanning through all elements inside each array, you can have only 1 `For` loop, and the other one will use the `Application.Match` function to find matches between the arrays.

This should save you a lot of code run-time when comparing large size arrays.

**Note**: I've replaced your `match` variable with `isMatch` , `match` is not the best name for a variable (since there is a function with the same name)

**Edit 1**: removed the `isMatch` variable, as it's not needed.

**Sub-Code**

```
Dim x
For Each x In arr
    If IsError(Application.Match(x, varr, 0)) Then '<-- no match between elements inside arrays
        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .Range("L" & .Range("L" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = x
        End With
    Else '<-- there is a match between arrays
        ' do nothing , raise a "MsgBox"
    End If       
Next x
```

Comment: And, of course, you can get rid of `isMatch` entirely by placing the contents of the `If Not isMatch Then` `...` `End If` block at the spot where `isMatch = False` currently is.

Comment: You're right, I'm after 12 hours day at work, not optimizing

Comment: I'm just starting my 12 hours at work, so I'm bright and fresh and raring to go!

Comment: @YowE3K removed the `isMatch` , now that I'm fresh after a good nights sleep :)

Comment: And I am about to turn in for the night!  Won't be easy to sleep though - still too hot :( Hopefully we'll get a nice cold southerly coming through soon though. :)